# How to seperate two swap partitions Ubuntu is using? One I have created for Kali

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, kali-linux, swap

I installed fresh Ubuntu and then Kali.
Installed Ubuntu with "/", "/home" and Swap partition. Left unallocated space for Kali.
After Ubuntu, I installed Kali in similar way as above. Kali was recognizing Swap of Ubuntu but I created a new one for this.

I see Ubuntu is using two swap now.

```
$ swapon
NAME      TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda3 partition 46.6G   0B   -1
/dev/sda7 partition   28G   0B   -2
```

Kali is also showing two swap in use. How to separate it?

Also, Kali has given warning for grub/UEFI/Boot loader at the end of installation. Don't remember exactly, but I can see Kali has overtaken grub. Both, Ubuntu and Kali, can be selected at boot time. So, no problem here.

I see `/etc/fstab` of Kali is having two swap entries. But Ubuntu's `/etc/fstab` is having only one entry.
     I removed one swap entry from Kali's `fstab` but no use. Both Kali and Ubuntu are showing two swap output for `swapon`.

I thought to solve swap so that sleep/hibernate and other issue don't come later.

I want Ubuntu as normal and safe installation for work and Kali for experiment. If anything that need to change for trouble free Ubuntu then I am ready to change as both are new with no files there.

Comment: Updated. Added more clarity.

Comment: Why don’t you want to share the swap partitions? You could use a single swap for both Ubuntu and Kali. Also, 46.6GiB and 28GiB is *way* too much swap.

Comment: I read that sleep/hibernate won't work correctly with shared swap. That's why I want separate one.

Comment: You want to hibernate both Kali and Ubuntu simultaneously?

Comment: You won't remember after some time that you have hibernated another system two days back. Is there absolutely no issue other than hibernate/sleep in shared swap?

Comment: No, there’s no other issue. There are other issues with hibernating multiple operating systems, it’s not something I would try (in particular, you can’t share any file system among the different environments).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65400/discussion-between-satya-prakash-and-stephen-kitt).

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix your `/etc/fstab` file, it probably has both swaps on Ubuntu and Kali, just erase the partition that you don't want to use on each and reboot.

About the booting, whenever you update grub on any of both distros, they'll update your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file and it will have the latest grub from the latest updated distro, (Kali is the blue and Ubuntu the purple if I'm not wrong) if you just want to update grub once, you can uninstall grub from one of the two distros and whenever you update the distro with `grub` installed, it will automatically reconfigure and search for the other distro too.

Comment: From Ubuntu, I see one swap in /etc/fstab.
`# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=15228eb0-15a1-4900-9f46-0dd1516b26ca none            swap    sw              0       0`

Comment: please be sure that this is not a known issue like [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6192) and if you are using GPT as label, then you can disable it with `systemctl mask dev-sdXY.swap` where X is the letter and Y the number of the partition

Comment: I saw fstab of Kali was having two swap entries. I removed one which I created for Ubuntu but nothing has changed. I see, change in fsab in Kali is done and stayed.

Comment: Also my Laptop is UEFI based, if it matters.

Comment: Yes UEFI means that you are using a GPT label on your disk, refer to last comment and try systemctl...

Comment: Sorry. I am not good in Admin part of Linux. But according to the github link, there swap got generated automatically. But in my case both swaps are generated by me during installation. One each for both OS. If I mask one then I cannot have separate one for each OS.